# Jenkins Build on Git Commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Currently, we trigger build jobs based on Git commits and life is good.  However, we are seeing an uptick in commits of non-code, ie. various forms of documentation and it is slowing down our build cycle.  Is there a way to screen to only build on commits of certain file types such as *.py, *.tf, etc? Or does Jenkins not have that level of visibility?

Comment: You could use a more explicit question title "Only trigger Jenkins build for certain file extensions in git commit".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the git trigger you are using, some options could help you limit when the job is run (for example, by excluding a gerrit topic). However, these commits won't be validated which should not allow the code to be merged.

I rather suggest changing your pipeline definition to check the nature of the changes. You could use the `git diff` command to run the longer stages only when the extensions you listed were modified. The code to integrate will vary depending on if you are using a Jenkinsfile, and how stages are built. In pure bash, here's an example:

```bash
if git diff --name-only master | grep -E '\.(py|tf)$'; then
    # Run lengthy CI stages
fi
```

Comment: No, right now the builds pipelines are built through the Jenkins console.  There is no Jenkinsfile or pipeline code, bash or groovy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the includeRegion and ExcludeRegion

```
    checkout scmGit(
           branches: [[name: '*/master']],
           extensions: [[$class: 'PathRestriction', 
           excludedRegions: '''
               myapp/var/*
           ''', 
           includedRegions: '''
               myapp/src/main/web/.*\\.py
               myapp/main/.*\\.tf
               myapp/src/main/web/.*\\.py
           '''], 
           cleanBeforeCheckout()], 
           userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId:GitHTTPSCredentials,url:ManifestRepoUrl]])
```

Check this for reference https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin#polling-ignores-commits-in-certain-paths